# How do I get an extended title bar in Ubuntu Unity?

Tags: linux, ubuntu-unity

Applications such as Mozilla Firefox and Ubuntu Software Center are able to extend the title bar gradient down into their toolbar area. Example follows:

[image: Screenshot illustrating the extended title bar effect in Ubuntu Unity]

How can I achieve the same effect in my application?

Comment: Make a gradient under your toolbar of the same color?

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 3):

First, the two applications that you mention are built using different toolkits and technologies and thus employ different methods to do what you're willing to do. While Firefox uses `XUL/GTK2`, USC uses `GTK3`. I'll explain both approaches.

1. Ubuntu Software Center is built using `GTK3`, and thus it's toolbar gradient is defined in the theme css file. The code that achieves this is

   ```
   /* primary-toolbar */
   .primary-toolbar,
   .primary-toolbar .toolbar,
   .primary-toolbar.toolbar {
   -GtkWidget-window-dragging: true;

   background-image: -gtk-gradient (linear, left top, left bottom,
                                    from (shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.96)),
                                    to (shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.4)));
   border-bottom-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.1);
   border-top-color: shade (@dark_bg_color, 1.09);
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px 0 1px 0;

   color: @dark_fg_color;
   text-shadow: 0 -1px shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.7);

   box-shadow: inset 0 1px shade (@dark_bg_color, 0.94);
   }
   ```

   In order to use this in your gtk3 application, you have to assign the class `primary-toolbar` to your toolbar. For appropriate documentation on that, check out [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.5/GtkStyleContext.html#GTK-STYLE-CLASS-TOOLBAR%3aCAPS).
2. Firefox is built using XUL and uses GTK2 to render the widgets on GNU/Linux distributions such as Ubuntu. The styling for the `tab-bar` of Firefox comes from the appearance definition of `menubar` as defined in the `gtkrc` file of the concerned theme. In the case of default theme Ambience, it is

   ```
   style "menubar" = "dark" {
     engine "murrine" {
       textstyle = 2
       text_shade = 0.33
       gradient_shades = {1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0}
       lightborder_shade = 1.0
     }
   }
   ```

It is possible to achieve the effect in other toolkits with different methods, but it is recommended that you write your application in gtk3 so as to use native styling.

Comment: I'm using Qt - is there any way to call into GTK and retrieve the appropriate colors?

Comment: When running under a `gtk` environment like Unity, Qt uses a theme renderer called `Qgtkstyle`, which uses the current `gtk2` theme to render the widgets. If you try to use `GtkStyleContext` within your application, then you'll get an error that you can't run gtk2 and gtk3 within the same process. I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903518/gtk3-getting-a-styles-class-property). Though it doesn't tell much, it hints at a solution that can be used, but it'll force you to style the whole application by hand.

Comment: You could also do this. Spawn a child process before the application's initialization, and use it to get the properties through GtkStyleContext. Then use use these properties to draw a custom style for your toolbar. Please note I have no idea if you could actually do this in Qt, it's just a wild guess.